# Show text box when checkbox clicked and keep showing after page reload

Tags: javascript

I have written a JavaScript function that shows a text input field when a checkbox is clicked. The essence of the function is basically to change the text box display property from "none", to "block" on checkbox click. This works fine, and thus when I check the box I see the text field, and when I uncheck the box, the text box hides.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to keep the text box showing after the page is refreshed. This is where I am stuck.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to store your state in a cookie and read it after load to get back to the same state : [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596/5546267 even with this one you need an example ?

Comment: Also, I should add - I have decided to add a "Save" button to the form which contains the checkbox scenario I speak of above, is there anyway I can use that to obtain the result I am looking for?

Comment: @Eric you don't need the 'save' , just put a set/erase cookie in the code that hide/display you input

Comment: @Eric if you still can't get it work after trying, edit your post and put your code with your test, I'll take a look ;)

Comment: Cool thanks! Much appreciated! Is doing something like local storage a better or worse option, and checking on page load whether the item is null or not?

Comment: Cookie is a local browser storage, so I don't really understand your question... ?